# How can I make a custom field type in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I want to make a custom form field in symfony2 named `daterange`, which will extends the default symfony date type form field and take date range(start date and end date) into two different text-box.

Comment: Have you published the code somewhere?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cause I don't like twig template engine this example only for PHP templating

**What you need is to make:**

1. New `TestBundle\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateRangeType` which extends `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`

   Here you should:
   a. write your own getParent, getName, buildForm methods
   b. getParent return 'field'
   c. getName return 'daterange'
   d. buildForm has `$builder->add('start', ...)->add('end', ...)->setAttribute('widget', 'daterange')`
2. Add it to the DI (config.yml as example)

```
    services:
        form.type.daterange:
            class: TestBundle\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateRangeType
            tags:
                -  { name: form.type, alias: daterange }
```

3. Create new widget for it in `TestBundle/Resources/views/Form/daterange_widget.html.php`
   you can take date widget as example. `Src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views/Form/date_widget.html.php`
4. Add to config (config.yml as example)

```
   framework:
       templating:
           form:
               resources:
                   - 'TestBundle:Form'
```

And for more widget customization as nefo_x said check [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Answer (score 6):

In order to do that, you need to add the following lines into `app/config/config.yml`

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'YourSuperBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

then in `src/Your/SuperBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block daterange_widget %}
     ... do the customization.
{% endblock %}
```

For additional reference please read [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) of Symfony 2.0 book.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the path for `fields.html.twig` - it's not obvious in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [good entry](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) in official cookbook on creating custom field type