# How to reference twig for custom field types in dedicated bundle?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am (still) trying to introduce http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input into a dedicated bundle. As far, I have a type as a child of text and a data transformer that converts comma-separated strings into arrays of Objects and vice versa.

Now I want to decorate the text field with the JQuery code linked above. As far as I understand, I have to define a block like

```
{% block manytomanycomboselector_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
  {{ block('text_widget') }}
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#{{ id }}").tagsInput();
    });
  </script>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock manytomanycomboselector_widget %}
```

in `[MyTypeBundle]Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig`

Now, both the documentation and the answers for [this question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506110/how-can-i-make-a-custom-field-type-in-symfony2) state that I have to reference `fields.html.twig` somewhere either in the template that uses the form or in `app/`, but this doesn't seem to be necessarily for other field-type bundles, though I cannot see in their code why.
What do I have to configure inside the bundle besides this block in this file?

Also I didn't get where I have to put the css and js requirements for the header and how I deal with general requirements like jQuery itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue & I resolve it by merging my field template in the `twig.form.resources` parameter.

So, in the DI extension of my bundle (MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php), I add:

```
$container->setParameter('twig.form.resources', array_merge(
    array('MyBundle:Form:field_widget.html.twig'),
    $container->getParameter('twig.form.resources')
));
```

Be aware, your bundle must be registered after the `TwigBundle` in your `AppKernel`.

EDIT:

A form field is not linked to any JS or CSS. So, IMO, you have 2 solutions.

Firstly, you directly wrap your JS & CSS in your field template and your bundle stays stand-alone.

Secondly, you instruct final users that they need to include manually some JSS & CSS each time they use your field type.

The IoFormBundle & GenemuFormBundle uses the second solution like explain in their documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, though I still don't understand how it works at IoFormBundle or GenemuFormBundle. Still stuck with js and css.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense and at least solves the problem how to handles dependencies on e.g. jQuery von multiple packages.

Comment: This will work, but there is one important point: your bundle must be registered after the Twig bundle.

Comment: Yes, I have just updated my answer to reflect your comment. Additionally, with more experience, I would recommend you to prepend the resource instead of appending it in order to let end users the ability to override your form fragment.