# Creating custom field types in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

How would one go about creating a custom form field type for Symfony 2? There is only this page I can find on the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a custom field type in symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506110/how-can-i-make-a-custom-field-type-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible answer is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506110/how-can-i-make-a-custom-field-type-in-symfony2). Be more specific if you want to get more specific answer.