# Symfony2: How do i validate start and end dates of an entity?

Tags: symfony

I am using start and end dates over multiple forms, but these properties are in a single entity. Now is there a way to compare the dates and display appropriate error messages inside each form.

Could anyone guide me for a best way to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be, on my opinion, to create your own form field with these 2 dates and its own validation rules. But this requires some strong symfony2 knowledges.
Here are some useful links about custom form field types creation :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html
- [How can I make a custom field type in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506110/how-can-i-make-a-custom-field-type-in-symfony2)
- http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/286-creating-a-custom-form-field-type-in-symfony-2

A quick and dirty way is to add a callback validation for each form implementing start and end date. More infos over here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: Thanks! callback validation did the job perfectly.