# Overwriting Core Symfony2 Components

Tags: php, symfony

Alright, Gonna be honest. Dont like some of the decisions symfony decided to take with their core files, so im trying to overwrite them. For example

`Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FieldType.php`

im Trying to change the name that gets rendered if a FormView has a parent because they do some cool string formating...

Im just trying to make it so the `$fullName` and `$id` are both `$form->getName()`;

```
 public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {
        $name = $form->getName();

        if ($view->hasParent()) {
            $parentId = $view->getParent()->get('id');
            $parentFullName = $view->getParent()->get('full_name');

            // Custom Logic
            //$id = sprintf('%s_%s', $parentId, $name);
            //$fullName = sprintf('%s[%s]', $parentFullName, $name);
            $id = $form->getName();
            $fullName = $form->getName();
        } else {
            $id = $name;
            $fullName = $name;
        }

        $types = array();
        foreach ($form->getTypes() as $type) {
            $types[] = $type->getName();
        }

        $view
            ->set('form', $view)
            ->set('id', $id)
            ->set('name', $name)
            ->set('full_name', $fullName)
            ->set('errors', $form->getErrors())
            ->set('value', $form->getClientData())
            ->set('read_only', $form->isReadOnly())
            ->set('required', $form->isRequired())
            ->set('max_length', $form->getAttribute('max_length'))
            ->set('pattern', $form->getAttribute('pattern'))
            ->set('size', null)
            ->set('label', $form->getAttribute('label'))
            ->set('multipart', false)
            ->set('attr', $form->getAttribute('attr'))
            ->set('types', $types)
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built a helper function.

```
public function fixForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $form)
{
    foreach($form as &$child)
    {
        $name = $child->get('full_name');
        $id = $child->get('id');
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/^(?<form>.+)\[(?<ele>.+)\]/', $name, $matches);
        if(isset($matches['ele']))
            $child->set('full_name', $matches['ele']);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/^(?<first>.+)_(?<second>.+)/', $id, $matches);
        if(isset($matches['second']))
            $child->set('id', $matches['second']);
    }
    return $form;
}
```

and its working. Just call this when you need to fix the form

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can try is to build your own Form Type.

You can put your own Form Type to your Bundle that you have a clean structure something like ("TestBundle/Form/Type").

In this fieldtype you can make your changes you need.

[How can I make a custom field type in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506110/how-can-i-make-a-custom-field-type-in-symfony2)

Here is a helpfull post that shows hot to make a custom Field Type.

Its a short hint and i hope you find a good solution and can tell us if its working and how you solved it.

Comment: unfortunately, the changes i make, need to be made to every fieldtype. I'd like to avoid rewriting all the field types just to change the name

Comment: Have you thought about to solve this problem in Twig? There are some methods to customize a form and change the fields in the template. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: like i said above, doing it in twig would require me to change all the `form_widget`'s and im trying to avoid that